# What is the definition of Hamiltonian derivation in Poisson algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let consider a Poisson algebra P with Poisson bracket $\{,\}$. Let consider a derivation map $d_{a}: P \to P$ defied by $d_{a}=\{a,x\}$ for $a \in P$ which is both a Lie algebra and associative algebra derivations. What is called this type pf derivation? Is it called

> Hamiltonian derivation
> ?

Comment: If it is a derivation of the Poisson structure, I’d call it a Poisson derivation.

Comment: The bracket is the derivation. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket